# Почему не срабатывает редирект в CakePHP?

Tags: php, framework, php-frameworks, cakephp

Вот код

```
class ArticlesController extends AppController {

public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
public $components = array('Session');
public $uses = array('Category', 'Article');

public function index() {
    return $this->redirect('http://www.example.com'); 
    //$this->redirect('http://www.example.com'); так тоже не работает           
}}
```

при попытке произвести редирект появляется пустой (белый) экран, сделал всё как описано в документации. В чём может быть причина?

Comment: Белый экран чаще всего говорит лишь об ошибке, посмотрите логи ошибок

Answer (score 1):

в файле контроллера нужно указать кодировку "Преобразовать в UTF-8 без BOM"

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?